# Postgresql Sequence Hopping

Tags: postgresql, restore, amazon-rds, sequence, aws-aurora

I have recently migrated (dump and restore) my database from **AWS RDS PostgreSQL v12 to Aurora Serverless v2 PostgreSQL v14.6**. The issue is we have setup sequencing in a table on old RDS, now in the new serverless v2 the **sequencing is hopping** from one digit to another. **Hopping Example - 1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22,23,24,25,32**. I have tried to delete the old sequence and created new one, but no luck.

Please let me know your thoughts in sorting this issue.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Gaps in sequences are by design and expected.

Comment: Gaps doesn't happen when the sequence is in RDS Database. The Gaps happens when the sequence is in aurora instance and scales.

Comment: Well, maybe Aurora handles sequences differently than RDS. Both are not "vanilla" Postgres installations so it's hard to tell. Maybe Aurora defines the CACHE attribute for the sequence. Or maybe Aurora uses a completely different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior with sequences. They skip values whenever there is a crash, an error, or even when you disconnect from the database (depending on your `CACHE` setting). See the warning in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, the value obtained by `nextval` is not reclaimed for re-use if the calling transaction later aborts. This means that transaction aborts or database crashes can result in gaps in the sequence of assigned values. That can happen without a transaction abort, too. For example an `INSERT` with an `ON CONFLICT` clause will compute the to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required `nextval` calls, before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the `ON CONFLICT` rule instead. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects *cannot be used to obtain “gapless” sequences*.

Read [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for details.